# Add cell comment using input box

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a comment to a cell using the inputbox. When the input box appears, the person is asked to select the cell where the comment is (cell could be on a different sheet) but i keep getting error.

Here is what i have so long

```
Sub SetComment()
Dim rSelected As Range
rSelected = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                        "Select cell with comment.", _
                        Title:="Cell comment box", Type:=2)
      With ActiveCell
         .AddComment
         .Comment.Text Text:= rSelected.value
      End With
   End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run it?

Comment: You want `Type:=8` [read more about the `Type` parameter here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox)

Comment: I get the runtime error 91. "Object variable or with block variable not set". I have also changed it to 8 but same error.

Comment: You also need `Set rSelected = Application.InputBox(...`

Comment: @Alex K that worked perfect thank you. Maybe add that as answer so i can mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using `Type:=8` for your input box whenever you assign an object refeence to a variable you need the `Set` keyword:

```
Set rSelected = Application.InputBox(...
```